# Batch Error GOTO was not expected at this time

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writting a program in batch using notepad++ and here's my code :

```
if %line1%==1 (
echo PLEASE ENTER THE PASSWORD TO CONTINUE
set /p password="PASSWORD:"
IF %PASSWORD%==%LINE2% GOTO PASSSUCCESS 
IF NOT %PASSWORD%==%LINE2% GOTO PASSERROR 
)
if %line1%==0 goto main menu
```

when i run the above code in cmd i get the following error :

GOTO was not expected at this time

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting and processing the `Password` variable within a single block so you need to have delayed expansion enabled. This should fix it:

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

if %line1%==1 (
echo PLEASE ENTER THE PASSWORD TO CONTINUE
set /p password="PASSWORD:"
REM Note how Password is in delayed expansion notation below.
IF !PASSWORD!==%LINE2% GOTO PASSSUCCESS 
IF NOT !PASSWORD!==%LINE2% GOTO PASSERROR 
)
if %line1%==0 goto mainmenu
```

As for the "why" you are getting this error: If you do not have delayed expansion on then the parser does not know what the value of `Password` is when the block is parsed, so it looks like this when executed:

```
echo PLEASE ENTER THE PASSWORD TO CONTINUE
set /p password="PASSWORD:"
IF ==<Line2Value> GOTO PASSSUCCESS 
IF NOT ==<Line2Value> GOTO PASSERROR
```

Note the where `Password` should be is empty. This is because it is not known at the time of parsing (again the entire block is parsed all at once before being executed). By enabling delayed expansion, each line would essentially be parsed sequentially so the value entered in the 2nd line would be available for the subsequent comparisons within the block.

Comment: thank you sir but there seems that something is wrong in the last line please help      if %line1%==0 goto main menu

Comment: @DebojyotiRoy - Ah yes, `mainmenu` just needed to be a single word. This should match the respective label in your batch script.